# BST in Data Structures the add() method

Tags: java, data-structures

I just need a little direction to solve this Data Structure problem.  I have to create an add() method for a BST.  I know how to do the recursive solution to this problem but what is a non-recursive solution to this?  Here is my Class.

```
import java.util.*;

public class BST 
{
// instance variables
private BSTNode m_root;
private int m_size;

// constructor
public BST()
{
    m_root = null;
    m_size = 0;
}

// add a value into the tree

    public void add(int v)
{   BSTNode current = m_root;
    if(current == null) {
    m_root=new BSTNode(v);
    m_size++;
    }
    else
    {
    while(current!=null) {
    if(current.getInfo() > v) {
    if(current.getLeft() == null) {
    m_root.setLeft(new BSTNode(v));
    m_size++;
    current=null;
    }
    else
    current = current.getLeft();

    }
    else if(current.getInfo()< v) {
    if(current.getRight() == null) {
    m_root.setRight(new BSTNode(v));
    current=null;
    m_size++;
    }
    else current = current.getRight();
}}}}

// get the size of the tree
public int size()
{
    return m_size;
}

// empty the tree
public void clear()
{
    m_root = null;
    m_size = 0;
}
}
```

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: Yes, please make an attempt to write the `add()` method.  When you find a bug, then ask a question about it here.

Comment: Sorry it is a bit messy so I didn't put it up.  I changed it a little with the help of the Answer below but that didn't work either...

Comment: The point isn't to dump all of your non-working code, the point is to ask a specific, targeted question. [ask].

Comment: I realize that I am asking a specific question about how I could make a non recursive add method for a BST and I am put up my non working code because you asked to see what doesn't work.

Comment: But why didn't it work? What specifically did you expect, and what did you get instead? For instance, did you try a particular input and it failed? How did it fail? What result were you expecting? Why were you expecting that result? What is your hypothesis about why that could be happening? What hypotheses did you test and find incorrect? Try to be scientific about it.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out!

```
  public void add(int v)
    { BSTNode current = m_root;
    if(current == null) {
    m_root=new BSTNode(v);
    m_size++;

    }
    else
    {
    while(current!=null) {
    if(current.getInfo()==v)
    {current=null;}
    else if(current.getInfo() > v) {
    if(current.getLeft() == null) {
    m_root.setLeft(new BSTNode(v));
    m_size++;
    current=null;
    }
    else
    current = current.getLeft();

    }
    else if(current.getInfo()< v) {
    if(current.getRight() == null) {
    m_root.setRight(new BSTNode(v));
    current=null;
    m_size++;
    }
    else current = current.getRight();
    }}
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BSTNode current = m_root;
if(current == null) {
    current = new BSTNode(v);
    return;
}
while(true) {
    if(current.key > v) {
        if(current.left == null) {
            current.left = new BSTNode(v);
            break;
        }
        else
            current = current.left;
    }
    else if(current.key < v) {
        if(current.right == null) {
            current.right = new BSTNode(v);
            breakl;
        }
        else current = current.right;
    }
}
```

Comment: This did work but out of curiosity what does .key mean?  I haven't see that yet

Comment: I may call it .value better :)